# CGAL: can't chose iterator correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, cgal

I build a convex hull 3d in CGAL library from point in stream .txt file and want to insert them into output .txt file by copying. 
The problem is about to chose iterator for std::copy that can sort out vertices in container *Polyhedron_3 poly*. Here is my code:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_3.h>
#include <CGAL/algorithm.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K>                     Polyhedron_3;
typedef K::Segment_3                              Segment_3;
// define point creator
typedef K::Point_3                                Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Creator_uniform_3<double, Point_3>  PointCreator;
//a functor computing the plane containing a triangular facet
struct Plane_from_facet {
  Polyhedron_3::Plane_3 operator()(Polyhedron_3::Facet& f) {
      Polyhedron_3::Halfedge_handle h = f.halfedge();
      return Polyhedron_3::Plane_3( h->vertex()->point(),
                                    h->next()->vertex()->point(),
                                    h->opposite()->vertex()->point());
  }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  std::ifstream fin("/Users/Arseniy/Documents/Course Work/Test Input.txt");
  std::ofstream fout("/Users/Arseniy/Documents/Course Work/Test Output.txt");

  CGAL::set_ascii_mode(fin);
  CGAL::set_ascii_mode(fout);

  std::istream_iterator< Point_3 >  in_start(fin );
  std::istream_iterator< Point_3 >  in_end;
  std::ostream_iterator< Point_3 >  out( fout, "\n" );

  std::vector<Point_3> points;
  std::copy(in_start, in_end, std::back_inserter(points));

  Polyhedron_3 poly;

  // compute convex hull of non-collinear points
  CGAL::convex_hull_3(points.begin(), points.end(), poly);

  cout << "The convex hull contains " << poly.size_of_vertices() << " vertices" << std::endl;
  cout << "The convex hull contains " << poly.size_of_facets() << " facets" << std::endl;

  // assign a plane equation to each polyhedron facet using functor Plane_from_facet
  std::transform(poly.facets_begin(), poly.facets_end(), poly.planes_begin(),Plane_from_facet());

  std::copy(poly.vertices_begin(), poly.vertices_end(), ostream_iterator<int>(fout, ", "));

  return 0;
}
```

I can't to determine type for *ostream_iterator<>*, it should be vertex_iterator, but its't.

Also i tried to describe

```
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex_iterator
```

But it's also a wrong decision.

Comment: Or you can propose another way to write points and facets into the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

`std::copy(poly.points_begin(), poly.points_end(), ostream_iterator<Point_3>(fout, ", "));`

Answer (score 0):

A polyhedron can be written into a file using the OFF file format.
You can simply write:

```
std::ofstream fout("output.off");
fout << poly;
```

Depending on your CGAL version you might need to include `CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h`

Comment: Could you be more precise? What exactly is not working?